# C++ multiple definition in Linux

Tags: makefile

When I make these files, g++ occurs two errors which are multiple definition and previous definition.

Makefile:

```
INCLUDE = -I/usr/X11R6/include/
LIBDIR  = -L/usr/X11R6/lib

FLAGS = -Wall
CC = g++
CFLAGS = $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDE)
LIBS =  -lglut -lGL -lGLU

glTestDemo.o: glTestDemo.cpp headers.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c glTestDemo.cpp

display.o: display.cpp headers.h
        $(CC) $(CLFAGS) -c display.cpp

glTestDemo: glTestDemo.o display.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) glTestDemo.o display.o -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $< $(LIBS)               # The initial white space is a tab

all: glTestDemo

clean:
        rm glTestDemo *.o
```

headers.h

```
#ifndef __HEADERS_H__
#define __HEADERS_H__

#include <GL/glut.h>

extern int NumPoints;

extern void incorrect_display (void);

#endif
```

display.cpp

```
#include "headers.h"

void
incorrect_display (void)
{
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPointSize (1.0);

    glDrawArrays (GL_POINTS, 0, NumPoints);

    glFlush ();
}
```

glTestDemo.cpp

```
#include "headers.h"

int NumPoints = 5000;

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition (50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize (600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow ("Test title");
    glutDisplayFunc (incorrect_display);
    glutMainLoop ();
    return 0;
}
```

The error message like that after I type make all :

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: glTestDemo.o: multiple definition of 'NumPoints'
/usr/bin/ld: glTestDemo.o: previous definition here
/usr/bin/ld: error: glTestDemo.o: multiple definition of 'main'
/usr/bin/ld: glTestDemo.o: previous definition here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [glTestDemo] Error 1
```

I have make a shell script to test my c++ syntax and g++ flag and openGL flag, which is used by linking. It is success. Hence, I think it is the Makefile cause the error. But I can not find the problem for this.

Answer (score 4):

You're linking in the glTestDemo.o twice

```
glTestDemo: glTestDemo.o display.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) glTestDemo.o display.o -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $< $(LIBS
                                                           ^^
```

$< means the name of the first dependency of the target (which you listed as glTestDemo.o ) but you have also explicitly mentioned glTestDemo.o  . Remove the $< and it should link.

Better yet, use $^, which means "all dependencies" (glTestDemo.o display.o in your case) and you can just do:

```
glTestDemo: glTestDemo.o display.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS)
```

Read more about the special variables in Makefiles [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)